# Display HTML text in the Adobe Air Label

Tags: apache-flex, air, label, htmltext

I am trying to display HTML text inside the Label in my Adobe Air mobile application, so far

I realized that Label doesn't support HTML, I went through the few solutions I found so far on the web:

1. Instead of `Label` - User `TextArea` and then use:

   ```
   StyleableTextField(message.textDisplay).htmlText = messageText;
   ```

   and in the `TextArea` declaration - specify mobile skin

   ```
   <s:TextArea editable="false" selectable="false" skinClass="spark.skins.mobile.TextAreaSkin" id="message" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" paddingLeft="5" paddingRight="5" textAlign="left"/>
   ```

   First of all, HTML still doesn't work, instead of converted HTML it just shows me `.....` garbage, but even if it would have worked - TextArea component looks different than Label and doesn't feet in the design I am implementing.
2. User  `RichText` component - unfortunately it's not supported in mobile apps

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, HTML is *not* supported in the `Label` and `TextArea` components for Spark (it was supported in Halo, or the `mx` components).

The only Flex components that officially do support it are `RichText` and `RichEditableText`. The skins for these components are not mobile *optimized*, but they run on mobile just fine. You may run into some speed issues when using massive amounts of it, but you can still use them (as you can with most, if not all, other components that aren't mobile optimized).

Comment: Actually I already found this solution yesterday, but since your  answer is exactly the same - I'll accept it as answer.